# NullPointerException while accessing instance of application context in business logic. How to access an instance of application context?

Tags: java, spring

Looking out for your valuable suggestion/inputs.
Below are the actual xml files - ApplicationContext and JobSchedulerServiceContext.

--- ApplicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN"
"http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">
<beans>
<bean id="applicationContextImpl" class="com. services.ApplicationContextImpl" scope="singleton">
<property name="dataAcquisitionService">
<ref bean="dataAcquisitionService" />
</property>
<property name="equipDataAcquisitionService">
<ref bean="equipDataAcquisitionService" />
</property>
<property name="emailService">
<ref bean="emailService" />
</property>
<property name="externalIoService">
<ref bean="externalIoService" />
</property>
<property name="persistenceService">
<ref bean="persistenceService" />
</property>
<property name="messageService">
<ref bean="messageService" />
</property>
<property name="uiService">
<ref bean="uiService" />
</property>
</bean>

<bean id="controller" class="com.services.ColServiceController" scope="singleton">
<property name="applicationContextImpl">
<ref bean="applicationContextImpl" />
</property>
<property name="serviceName">
<value>Service Controller</value>
</property>
<property name="serviceMap">
<map>
<entry key="message">
<ref bean="messageService" />
</entry>
<entry key="persistence">
<ref bean="persistenceService" />
</entry>
<entry key="email">
<ref bean="emailService" />
</entry>
<entry key="dataAcquisition">
<ref bean="dataAcquisitionService" />
</entry>
<entry key="equipDataAcquisition">
<ref bean="equipDataAcquisitionService" />
</entry>
<entry key="jobScheduler">
<ref bean="jobSchedulerService" />
</entry>
<entry key="ui">
<ref bean="uiService" />
</entry>
<entry key="externalIo">
<ref bean="externalIoService" />
</entry>
</map>
</property>
</bean>
<bean id="applicationContextProvider" class="com.cymer.services.ApplicationContextProvid er">
</bean>
</beans>
```

--- JobSchedulerServiceContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN"
"http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">
<beans>
<bean id="jobSchedulerService" class="com. services.scheduler.JobSchedulerServiceImpl" scope="singleton">
<property name="applicationContextImpl">
<ref bean="applicationContextImpl" />
</property>
<property name="serviceManual">
<value>true</value>
</property>
<property name="serviceName">
<value>Job Scheduler</value>
</property>
<property name="jobSpecifiers">
<list>
<bean id="automatedDataSharingJob" class="com. services.scheduler.JobSpecifier" scope="singleton">
<property name="taskName">
<value>AutomatedDataSharingJob</value>
</property>
<property name="execClass">
<bean class="com.services.scheduler.job.AutomatedDataSha ringJob" scope="singleton">
<property name="applicationContextImpl">
<ref bean="applicationContextImpl" />
</property>
<property name="jobManual">
<value>false</value>
</property>
</bean>
</property>
</bean>

<bean id="runFullVacuumJob" class="com. services.scheduler.JobSpecifier" scope="singleton">
<property name="taskName">
<value>RunFullVacuumJob</value>
</property>
<property name="execClass">
<bean class="com. services.scheduler.job.RunFullVacuumJob" scope="singleton">
<property name="applicationContextImpl">
<ref bean="applicationContextImpl" />
</property>

</list>
</property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSharingUtil" class="com.datasharing.util.DataSharingUtil" scope="singleton">
</bean>

</beans>
```

And this is the original java class of product which is loading the application context by getting control from servlet controller. I was trying out to implement ApplicationContextAware and get an instance of current context

```
package com..services;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefin itionReader;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlAp plicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplica tionContext;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAwar e;
public class ColServiceController
extends ColServiceBase
implements ApplicationContextAware
{
public static final String S_SERVICE_CONTROLLER = "S_Service_Controller";
private static String[] appContexts =
{
"applicationContext.xml",
"dataAcquisitionServiceContext.xml",
"equipDataAcquisitionServiceContext.xml",
"emailServiceContext.xml",
"externalIoServiceContext.xml",
"jobSchedulerServiceContext.xml",
"messageServiceContext.xml",
"persistenceServiceContext.xml",
"statusDataEventAttributeContext.xml",
"uiServiceContext.xml",
};
private Map<String,ColService> serviceMap = new HashMap<String,ColService>();
public ColServiceController()
{
super(ColServiceController.class);
}

private static ApplicationContext appContext;

public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext()
{
return appContext;
}

public static ApplicationContext loadSpringContext(final String confPath)
{
ApplicationContext context = null;

// If a discrete conf location has been specified,
// load the bean definition files from there
if (!StringUtil.isEmpty(confPath))
{
System.err.println("Loading context files from: " + confPath);
final GenericApplicationContext ctx = new GenericApplicationContext();
final XmlBeanDefinitionReader xmlReader = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader(ctx);

for (int i=0; i < appContexts.length; i++)
{
final File file = new File(confPath + File.separator + appContexts[i]);
if (file.isFile())
{
System.err.println("Loading context file: " + file.getPath());
xmlReader.loadBeanDefinitions(new FileSystemResource(file));
}
else
{
System.err.println("Skipping: " + appContexts[i]);
}
}

ctx.refresh();
context = (ApplicationContext)ctx;
}
// ...otherwise, use the files located in the classpath
else
{
System.err.println("Loading services from classpath.");
context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(appContexts);
}

return context;
}

public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx) throws BeansException {
appContext = ctx; }}
```

But the getApplicationContext() is always returning NULL. Once i will get the reference to context , i need to reschedule the job.

I am not able to figure it out. Could anyone have a look at it?

Do suggest me the solution if you come across this. Thanks

Comment: This took a lot of reformatting and could probably still use some more.  You'll want to check to make sure I didn't mess anything up when I edited it.

Answer (score 3):

Make your class implement [`ApplicationContextAware`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextAware.html). You will be passed the `ApplicationContext` in the setter method that you are forced to implement.

Update:

- make the `context` field non-static.
- get rid of the static method completely
- read the spring official documentation - using `static` methods is never a good idea with spring beans. Their *instances* live inside the spring container, and they are instantiated by spring. If it is *you* who instantiates your classes or invoke static methods, then spring does not work.

Comment: did u go through my class which i have shared. is anything wrong in that? do let me know.

Comment: @BKumar as I commented on your other post - use the "edit" feature on your original question - don't add answers. And use formatting. Right now I can't read and follow your data.

Comment: Are you talking about this method ---- public static ApplicationContext loadSpringContext(final String confPath) ??
I made context field non-static, but still the prob does exist.

Comment: how do you refer to your bean? Do you instantiate it, or get it from spring context? Do you inject it. Show the whole structure of your application

Comment: @BKumar - no. Add this info to the question above by editing it.

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"context.xml"});
```

Comment: This would create a new instance of ApplicationContext. While i do wanna have a reference to existing one i.e. the already available applicationcontext.